# I can't manage, add or edit terms on "Managed Metadata Service"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I can't manage, add or edit terms on "Managed Metadata Service"

[image]

note: the current user is farm admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add your farm admin account into term store administrators. to add follow the instruction below.

- Click on the **Managed MetaData Service** from the left side
- on right side you will **Term Store Administrators**
- Add the farm admin account here.
  [image]